# How many combinations are possible: English alphabet A-Z and digits 0-9 in a set of 12.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, combinatorics-on-words

How many combinations can be made from a 12 set string of letters and number that can be repeated and used more than once in any order. Ie- TD3GD3BK6K7T and would be different than T7K6KB3DG3DT or KKTT733DDGB6.

Comment: caps and small letters or just caps?

Comment: $36^{12}$ $ $ $ $

Comment: All caps I guess k=K. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Each character in the string can be any one of the (26+10) possible characters. So there are $36^{12}$ possible combinations.